Is the set of left ideal classes of a group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ finite?
Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of isomorphism classes of left ideals of $\mathbb Z[G]$ which sasistfy the property: $$\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z} I\cong \mathbb Q[G],\quad\text{as $\mathbb Q[G]$-modules.}\quad (*)$$  Is it true that the set $\mathcal I$ is finite? Does anyone have a reference for this?
Note that two left ideals $I,J$ satisfying property $(*)$  are isomorphic, if and only if
$$I=J\alpha,\quad\text{for some $\alpha\in \mathbb Q[G]^\times$}.$$
So this is a very similar context to the usual one from rings of integers.

This paper https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~stevenhagenp//ants7/0035.pdf has several references. In particular,  the first paragraph of the introduction seems to say that the answer to your question is YES.
